# How Reddit implements its Chat feature

Tags: web

I don't understand how Chat function in Reddit web application work.

When I send message to other user Through Chat function and open Developer tools > Network tab to see requests sent. I see a `POST` request to `https://www.reddit.com/` with request body of 771 length. However, I cannot find my sent message here. If I send message with 10 characters, the POST request body will be 771 in length. If I send message with 100 characters, the POST request body will still be 771 in length.

So how is my message sent to server or to other user?

Comment: Did you check if theres any websockets opened?

Comment: @DownloadPizza Yes, there are websockets, but I don't see any relevant data sending here.

Comment: @DownloadPizza, found it, it is indeed send through websockets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment. Reddit uses websockets to send data back and forth. Unlike http, websockets are permanently open and can be used to send, but nore importantly receive data without reloading the site. They are however also good for sending as no new requests have to be made